# My wordpress links display to the wrong site

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, hyperlink

My wordpress sites redirects to the wrong location. Go to www.theladieschampion.com

On the left side bar you have the option to click on social media links. When you click on the social media link instead of going to www.facebook.com/theladieschampion it goes to:

www.theladieschampion.com/www.facebook.com/theladieschampion

Why is the happening? Even when I create buttons that lead to links on mysite the links URL gets placed over the sites URL. Please Help

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/theladieschampion Use link with https://

Comment: I have checked and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You must be using your anchor tag as

```
<a href="www.facebook.com/something">Facebook</a>
```

Change this to

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/something">Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your code should look like below:--
    <div class="social-links">
                <ul>
                                    <li>
                        <a class="social fb" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/TheLadiesChampion/">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                        <a class="social tw" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/theladieschamp_">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                    <li>
                        <a class="social gg" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/+TheLadiesChampionOfficial/posts">
                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                </ul>
            </div>``
```